# How can I make an html button that passes a parameter?

Tags: html, forms, button, hyperlink, parameter-passing

I want a html button with parameter functionality.

`new/?sorting=desc` is the url that it should link to. But when I try, the parameter is not passed. How should it be done? I tried both the methods below but none worked.

```
<FORM METHOD="GET" ACTION="./?sorting=desc">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Äldst först">
</FORM>
```

I want buttons that behave like these links:

`<a href="./?sorting=desc">Äldst först</a>
<a href="./?sorting=asc">Nyast först</a>`

Comment: i didnt get what you needed ??..when you click a button you need to redirect to a link ??

Comment: You will need to do this with a bit of Javascript. Do you have jQuery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something to act as a link, then you should use a link.

That said:

When you submit a GET form, the query string is removed from the action and a new one is generated from the data in the form.

You need to store the data in hidden inputs.

```
<form action="/social/tracking/new/">
     <input type="hidden"
            name="sorting"
            value="desc">
     <input type="submit" 
            value="Nyast först">
</form>
<form action="/social/tracking/new/">
     <input type="hidden"
            name="sorting"
            value="asc">
     <input type="submit" 
            value="Sort the other way">
</form>
```

Comment: This code can only pass the "desc" value, not the "asc".

Comment: @Heru-Luin — It's pretty obvious how to make it go the other way, but I've edited the answer to spell it out.

Comment: You now have 2 forms. It could work depending on what OP wants.
If he wants to dynamically change the sorting order or only have one form, this will not work.

Comment: @Heru-Luin — I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "dynamically" change the sorting order. Having only one form wasn't a requirement.

Comment: @Quentin I was talking about the possibility to have only one form. Depending on which submit button you click, the sorting order will change (cf my answer).

If you want to pass other parameters in the form, it would be better to have only one form (or you will be forced to duplicate the fields on each form, and use Javascript anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can use the code below.
This will fill a hidden input with the correct value when you click on one of the submit buttons.

```
<form method="get" action="./">
    <input type="hidden" name="sorting" id="sorting" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Äldst först" id="sort_desc" />
    <input type="submit" value="Nyast först" id="sort_asc" />
</form>
<script>
    $('#sort_desc').click(function(){
        $('#sorting').val('desc');
    });
    $('#sort_asc').click(function(){
        $('#sorting').val('asc');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There's no need to involve JavaScript in this at all.

Comment: Javascript is used to change the value ("asc" or "desc") of the hidden input depending if you click on "Nyast först" or "Äldst först".

Answer (score -4):

I think its not possible. A form is used to send data (mostly) via POST or GET. Your goal is to open a specific URL. I would create a standard  and would style it like a button. Whats the reason you want to use a button?